# Connect to Multiple Azure Active Directory with single application and get the user details

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need a ASP.Net application to connect to multiple Azure AD and fetch user details.
I should have only one tenant id , client id , client key to connect to multiple Azure AD.

Is this possible? And how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is certainly possible though you can't have a single tenant id. For each Azure AD your application will connect to, you will get a different tenant id.

For this to work, you just have to mark your application as `Multi Tenant`. Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Hi Gaurav, Thanks for your help...i have made my application as multi-tenant but how do i get this integrated application to appear in my other Active directories??